# Will i be able to create websites with a Macbook Pro by using the usuall website development s/w like PHP,CSS,XHTML or HTML

Tags: php

Will i be able to use the usuall website designing s/w on a MAcbook pro ro should i have to bother creating a website using Macbook pro.?

Comment: oh you can't do that with a mac <sarcastic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Dreamweaver, Netbeans and many other pieces of software will build websites on a MacBook pro. Apple even has iWeb.

Comment: @icktoofay, that's like notepad for mac right?

Comment: @Dagon: Yes, except it can also edit RTFs. So it's kind of like a combination of WordPad and Notepad.

Comment: @G abhinav, web develop and design can be done on any operating system. Well, at least the programming end since of course would need sofware's like photoshop or similar for designing and drawing.

Comment: @icktoofay so you ar tlling me that i dont have to worry about being able to design websites on Macbook Pro..?

Comment: @G Abhinav: I was joking; I was saying that you can create websites on almost any operating system that has a text editor and a web browser.

Comment: a web site is text, if you did not know this i worry about your ability to create a site on any type of computer. Now if you want to use a particular application, then that would need to have a copy that works on a particular OS

Comment: @icktoofay so working on Safari i can create websites that can be drawn on IE,Mozilla,Crome...right..?

Comment: @Dagon - I have to admit i do not know to create Websites,right now...but am gonna be able to do that in like 2months and then i do not wanne realise that Macbook Pro uses some diff s/w which i mite have to get buying original text editors and stuff...

Comment: @G abhinav - all good, macs are magic, enjoy.